# where can I upload json file?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, getjson

I have wrote a json file with data I will get it to recycleview in android but I don't know where can I upload this file to access it into android project

Comment: if you need it in the internet you simply have to make it in web space provider and retrieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store JSON file in your assets folder......

Comment: Use this http://www.json-generator.com/

You can upload your json here and they will also provide URL to access your JSON

Comment: ok .. how can I sent images or videos in JSON file ?? where can I save my data to sent it with JSON

Comment: You can save images/data on server and then just save link in your json you use

http://tinypic.com/   to save images on server

Comment: in json-generator.com I can't edit my JSON file the site generate a new JSON file with new url path

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do that:

1. Local Storage: You can save a JSON file in your project locally. (already answered by others)
2. Upload your JSON: You can upload your JSON at [jsonbin.io](https://jsonbin.io/) and it will generate an API that you can use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
void saveStringToFile(String path, String content) {
    try {
        File newFile = new File(path);
        newFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Constant.logD("File "+ newFile.getName()+ " is saved successfully at "+ newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Constant.logE("Unable to save file", e);
    }
}
```

Mention a path in a mobile sdcard like Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg" as path

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement:

1. Best option is to host it on a (web server if you have one)
2. If you don't, share the file on [GDrive](http://drive.google.com) or [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) (or similar hosting services which provide free storage). Share it with read-only access for your app to read from.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your json file in the assets folder and best option is host the json file on the server and use the data (API) in your project.